# How do you pronounce 협 correctly

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce the syllable 협 (hyeob) correctly in Korea?

I tried to listen in google translate but it is very difficult to make clear what part of the mouth that is actually being moved even when I had listen to it in slowmo. Tried to replicate it but it came out sounding different. Especially the "hy" part, the sound h and y seems to be fused in some unusual way, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: If you are an English speaker, try saying 'yup' but add an 'h' sound to the initial 'y'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *is* true that Korean ㅎ has a very wide range of allophones, more so than the English *h*. So your perception that the ㅎ sounds "different" in the syllable 협 is not just based on an error.

This is the concept of *allophones*, and Korean ㅎ has a very large number of them. From  Shin, Kiaer, Cha's 2012 [seminal work](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=99Ap68FkxawC&oi=fnd&pg=PA77), *The Sounds of Korean*:

```
Phoneme:  /h/
Major allophones: /ç/ before /j, i/ in word-initial position
                  /x/ before /ɯ/ in word-initial position
                  /ɸʷ/ before /u, o/ in word-initial position 
                  /h/ before all other vowels in word-initial position
                  /ʝ, ɣ, β, ɦ/ voiced counterparts in word-medial position
```

The fusion of the /h/ and the /j/ (the  sound) in Korean 협 results in the [voiceless palatal fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palatal_fricative) [ç], which is quite common in British and Australian English (**hu**e, pronounced [çʉː]), and also attested in American English. If you've studied German before, it is the *ich-Laut* of standard Hochdeutsch.

So 협  in IPA follows the allophonic change: /hjʌp/ -> [çʌ̹p̚]. Although it is most naturally pronounced this way, most English-speakers will be able to get away with the /hj/ being pronounced more like in English.

Note also that it may be affected by voicing if in the middle of a word, e.g. in the word [타협](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%ED%83%80%ED%98%91#Korean) "*compromise*".

Comment: @Tomsofty33 I don't think that /hj/ can go with /ʌ/ "short u" in native modern English phonotactics: the yod can only occur with the /uː/ "long u" phoneme.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 The notation [ʌ̹] I've just stolen from Wiktionary - it just says it's more rounded than the "cardinal" [ʌ], which you can tell from modern Korean speakers - to my ears it sounds a lot like [ɔ].

Comment: "the ich-Laut of standard Hochdeutsch".  Just to clarify a bit,  is this the ich-laut you are referring to? youtube.com/watch?v=HUKB4LxaRxw

Comment: I was trying to edit my first comment, before u replied..but...it got deleted.. O well.

Comment: @Tomsofty33 The first one is /ç/, although the second one is /x/ (what is called the ach-Laut). However, for the purposes of Korean you probably want to imitate Korean examples!

Comment: Hey, you were the one giving me thee example, using german, in the first place. I was just trying to clarify your statement..the link I posted was a video, so which  one do you refer to as "the first one" and "the second one"?

Comment: Imitating Korean example directly.... is not my level yet, i'm still a newbie trying to learn the correct korean pronunciation...at a slow pace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87188/discussion-between-michaelyus-and-tomsofty33).

Comment: It may seem paradoxical, but if you're learning Korean, you don't need to spend too much time worrying about the details of these allophones. Just consider them as rough guides. After all, even a native Korean speaker has little idea how many different allophones of ㅎ they make: it all happens automatically at a subconscious level. What's important is to be able to "recognize" a native ㅎ sound and make a similar sound when you speak. Mimicking the exact sound is much less important than, say, grammar or vocabulary.

Comment: Just a note for anybody doing research on this: There seem to be two books called The Sounds of Korean, from different writers: https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=99Ap68FkxawC&oi=fnd&pg=PA77#v=onepage&q&f=false, https://www.waterstones.com/book/the-sounds-of-korean/miho-choo/miho-choo/9780824859046

Comment: @user17915 Hmm I'll try and look into it....thanx